# React-Native: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I know the issue has been raised by many before me, yet I can't find a solution that works for me.
I am trying to launch my react-native app on my Windows terminal.
Following the React Native doc

- I installed the microsoft-openjdk11 so my environment runs on Java 11.
- I installed the Android Studio, Android SDK Platform 33, Android 13 (Tiramisu), Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image.

My environment variables look like this:

- ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
- ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
- Path = C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.20.101-hotspot\

Since I kept getting an error message when using the latest version of the command-line tools, I downgraded to the version 10. Now it seems to have let me accept the licenses:

[image: cmdline]

Now it should be working, but it doesn't:

[image: terminal vscode]

Anyone has an idea what I am missing?
Of course I have tried restarting the computer but nothing so far.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding on my own the solution and reason for my issue.

I indeed accepted all these licenses yet it was still showing the same error message: it was due to the location in which the licenses folder was created after I accepted all of them. In my case, it was automatically created in C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin, while the machine checks for it at C:\Users\thoma.android\avd\licenses. Simply go to the folder 'licenses' that was created, copy it and paste it where it should go: C:\Users\thoma.android\avd.

Then it worked :)
Hope that will help someone!!